# How to show tags on Tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I've looked a several questions on here that matched mine and tried doing the answers that were given. None of which worked for me. I don't know why.. Can somebody help me out?

I've put,

```
{block:HasTags}
    {block:Tags}
        <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
    {/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
```

Everywhere I can possibly think of.

Maybe my certain theme is overriding it?

Here's the code:
http://pastebin.com/jiCbC4fN

I would also like to know how to add a simple, small picture right below my links. Here's my blog to show you what I am talking about: http://buriedlies.tumblr.com/ [NSFW]

Answer (score 5):

The code that are trying to include shows tags under each post and needs to be included somewhere between `{block:Posts}` and `{/block:Posts}`. In addition, your posts must have tags if you want tags to be shown (that's why it's called `HasTags`). Tags are to be specified in the dedicated field when you're creating or editing a post.

If you are talking about a tag cloud, then Tumblr doesn't have a built-in one. However, you can integrate a third-party one. The most popular one is by Heather Rivers and can be found [on her site](http://rive.rs/projects/tumblr-tag-clouds).