# How to make Tags show in this Tumblr Theme that doesn't show?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making tags visible when using a Tumblr theme that doesn't show them](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/making-tags-visible-when-using-a-tumblr-theme-that-doesnt-show-them)

Here's the theme I'm using: http://themesbyjames.tumblr.com/escalation/

Comment: Also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22582/how-to-show-tags-on-tumblr-theme http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25674/how-to-make-tags-comments-notecounts-date-permalink-and-etc-visible http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19250/how-can-i-make-tags-visible-using-this-tumblr-theme

Answer (score 0):

You need a `{Block:HasTags}` with a code defining each tage (say `{block:Tags} <a href="/tagged/{Tag}" class="tag">#{Tag}</a>&nbsp;{/block:Tags`) somewhere inside your `{block:posts}`.

See the [Tumblr man page regarding tags](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tags) for the nitty-gritty.